# GoogleScript - Change "From" in MailApp

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, alias, macos-mail-app

I do not have access to our corporate No-reply Email address to use GmailApp.sendEmail as an alias, so I'm stuck with MailApp.sendEmail

I already have the reply-to corrected; but I am trying to get the actual FROM on the email to show something other than my email address, any suggestions?

```
   MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, "NO-REPLY@xxxxx.com", subject, message);
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I've looked into this extensively as I tried but the only way to do it is through ```GmailApp.sendEmail()``` and then you can send from an alias.

Comment: @Gav but I believe the email address has to be a real email address that you can confirm access to. (Yes/No?)

Comment: @Cooper - yes correct as when adding an alias in gmail you have to approve via a code sent to the email address you are adding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Answer:**

You can specify the option `noReply` in order to discourage recipients from responding to emails. However, you have to call the function `sendEmail` in a different way:
`sendEmail(recipient, subject, body, options)`
The parameter `options` is a Javascript option and looks like this:

```
options = {
  noReply: true
}
```

But keep in mind that if you use `noReply` you can't specify a `replyTo` address. If you want to provide one for them to reply I would specify it in the message. Futhermore, for future cases I recommend you to use `GmailApp` instead of `MailApp` as it has more features.

**References:**

- [MailApp.sendEmail](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendEmail(String,String,String,Object))
- [GmailApp.sendEmail](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#sendemailrecipient,-subject,-body,-options)

Comment: Sadly, I don't have access to the email address as an Alias to send using the Gmail send option.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to just create a custom Gmail account for running scripts. You can add a custom name and choose a good avatar

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).